# IF condition in DAX giving error "Cannot convert value 'FALSE' of type Text to type Date."

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to create a dashboard which has one single select dropdown of dates and what-if parameter in form of slider, which has values from 0 to 24.

I want to find sum of sales from Table **Fact_Sales**. Sales should be by **month** and **Year**.

Sales should be calculated for the period between **Start_Date** and **End_Date**.

Now **Start_Date** will come from the slider which will be from the below formula:

```
date(year(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key])),month(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key]))-Cust_Key[Cust_Key Value],1)
```

**End_Date** will come from the Dropdown -->

```
HASONEVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key])
```

`Cust_Key[Cust_Key Value]` -- >> This is slider value which sliders from 0 to 24 months

**The Problem :**

While calculating the calculated column from the below formula, I get error as **"Cannot convert value 'FALSE' of type Text to type Date."**

```
Is Date Filtered = If(datevalue('Fact Sale'[Delivery Date Key])>=datevalue(date(year(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key])),month(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key]))-Cust_Key[Cust_Key Value],1)) && datevalue('Fact Sale'[Delivery Date Key]) <= datevalue(HASONEVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key])),1,0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0T8u.png)

I have attached  error , dropdown and slider screenshots.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

[image]

**Update :**

I have updated the DAX calculation from calculated column to measure. The new formula which I made is:

```
Total Quantity = 
                     var SValue = SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key])
return
CALCULATE(sum('Fact Sale'[Quantity]),FILTER('Fact Sale',[Delivery Date Key] >= date(year(SValue),month(SValue)-Cust_Key[Cust_Key Value],1) && 
                                                        [Delivery Date Key] <= date(year(SValue),month(SValue),1)
))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error: function HASONEVALUE returns TRUE or FALSE. So your formula essentially reads:

```
... date(year(FALSE) ...
```

which makes no sense.

The function you were probably looking for is SELECTEDVALUE:

```
YEAR ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key] ))
```

and to avoid writing it many times you should store it in a variable, i.e.,

```
VAR Selected_Date = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Distinct Delivery Date Key] )
```

and then you can use Selected_Date in your formula.

I must point though that if you are trying to build a calculated column with this approach, it won't work. Calculated columns can not respond to slicers and other user actions.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. I implemented your suggestions and I am able to get rid of all the errors. I changed the calculation from calculated column to measure. However, now I am only able to see one month data. For example, If you see the newly attached screenshot, My table has only the data for one month, which is March 2013. However I want the numbers for 3 months - January 2013, February 2013 and March 2013, as the slider is showing 2. How can I connect the slider with the calculation..

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem without further information. I recommend to create a new question specifically for the new problem, and provide a good description/ diagram of your data model and relations, and  - ideally - a data sample to play with and an example of a desired result. You will have better chances to get help. For this question, if you feel like the original problem has been solved, mark it as resolved.